# Complicated SVN spanning multiple directories

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I work in programming for a machine manufacturing company.  We program multi-axis controllers, PLCs, HMIs, and other products, but all of them have their own programming environments and most of them were originally written for Windows 95 and haven't really been updated since.

A machine is capable of having multiple different drives, so multiple different programs in multiple languages, and the file structure for all the languages is specific to that programming environment.

One of the languages uses a projects file inside the install folder like so:

```
c:\MACHSHOP\ <- programming language installation folder
c:\MACHSHOP\PROJECTS\ <- contains a file for each project definition
c:\MACHSHOP\PROJECTS\INTERACT <- Dir containing subdir's of all project's code, with the same name as the project definition file.
```

Another language will just have a single directory in a Projects folder inside the installation directory, but it can't easily be moved to another location.

```
c:\directsoft\projects <- programs must reside in a subdir in here.
```

or even

```
c:\program3\projects <- Each program consists of 4-5 files located in here, no subdirs.
```

I am trying to find a version control software package that would allow me to create a project and then link the various project folders and files across these directories.  Is this even possible, and how can it be done if so?

Comment: Take a look at [Perforce](http://perforce.com). The thing with Perforce is that it allows you to create _views_ which specifies exactly how you want to check something out. You can rearrange directories, rename files in views, and even overlap to directories in the same working directory. It's more complex than Subversion and Git, but it does exactly what you want. Under 5 users and 2 views, and it's free.

Comment: Thanks, I've contacted their support staff to see what it would take to do this correctly.  Looks like the free version has been up'd to 20 users.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this kind of thing using [SVN externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html) which you link to other SVN repositories. Or if you want to use distributed version control which I recommend you can look into [Git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules). In each case you have links to other repositories which can point to different versions/branches, giving you lots of flexibility.